# select2 custom error message with jQuery validation plugin

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, jquery-validate

When I try to validate a select2 what I get is the same text as the label

```
 <div class="row">
     <div class="col-sm-12">
         <div class="form-group">
             <label for="cboMetodoPago">Método de pago <span class="required"></span></label>
             <select class="form-control select2-nosearch" id="cboMetodoPago" name="cboMetodoPago" required></select>
         </div>
     </div>
 </div>
```

This is how I configure the plugin

```
    $(".formsave").validate({
        highlight: function (element) {
            jQuery(element).closest('.form-group').addClass('has-error');
        },
        success: function (element) {
            jQuery(element).closest('.form-group').removeClass('has-error');
        },
        ignore: ["input[type=hidden]"],
        onfocusout: false,
        invalidHandler: function (form, validator) {
            var error = validator.numberOfInvalids();

            if (error) {
                validator.errorList[0].element.focus();
            }
        },
        message: {
            cboMetodoPago: {
                required: "Este campo es obligatorio"
            }
       }
    });
```

And the text I get is the same as the label inside the form-group

[image]

Any way to replace the text with the corresponding one?

Regards

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The object is called `messages`, not `message` as you have it.

```
messages: { // <- "messages", not "message"
    cboMetodoPago: {
        required: "Este campo es obligatorio"
    }
}
```

---

Based on your usage of `highlight`, you should use `unhighlight` instead of `success`.

```
highlight: function (element) {
    jQuery(element).closest('.form-group').addClass('has-error');
},
unhighlight: function (element) {
    jQuery(element).closest('.form-group').removeClass('has-error');
},
```

The `success` function is really meant for controlling the error message element, which is normally hidden when the element passes validation.  In other words, you can leverage the error `label` when the element passes validation to give another message or icon, like "passed" or a green checkmark.

Comment: You're right man, it was a typo. What's the difference between success and unhighlight?. success unhighlight the controls too.

Comment: @elchente23, it fires at slightly different times and it's meant to do something else entirely.  See my edited answer for explanation.